# Cake PHP 1.2 Admin revision to application. Prefix/Admin Routing?

Tags: cakephp, admin, cakephp-1.2

Currently the Auth component has been used to lock access to the application for anyone who isn't logged in. However the add action of the users_controller has been made available with routing so that they can 'register'. (**The whole point is that anyone can register to access the app's functionality, but I need to implement an unique admin user**)

```
Router::connect('/register', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'));
```

Accordingly a 'register' link has been placed on views/pages/home.ctp along with a login form:

```
<p>
     Only takes about 1 minute to <?php echo $html->link('register', '/register'); ?> and its free.
   </p>

   <div id="login">

    <h2>Login</h2>

   <?php
    if  ($session->check('Message.auth')) $session->flash('auth');
    echo $form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));
    echo $form->input('username', array('value' => 'billy'));
    echo $form->input('password', array('value' => 'billy'));
    echo $form->end('Login');
   ?>

   </div>
```

**views/elements/header.ctp:**

```
 <?php if($html->loggedIn()): ?>
        <ul class="right">
          <li><?php echo $html->link('Log Out', '/users/logout'); ?></li>
              </ul>
    </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- end nav -->
```

My massive problem is that I need to find a simple way, preferably without ACL of separating the edit action and delete action of the users_controller so that only an admin can edit and delete users.

My database structure for the users table requires a unique username(VARCHAR) and a unique id (INT)

Is there any simple way that I implement a check on the login form that says if the string entered for username is 'admin' or if the value for 'id' is equal to 1, then allow only this unique 'admin' user access to the edit and delete actions of the users controller? I imagine some routing may be involved to.

Or is activating the cake_admin user in the core a viable option?

I can make more of my code available on request. Please remember I am working with version 1.2

**users_controller.php:**

```
function edit($id = null) 
    {
    if(!$this->Session->read('Auth.User.admin') == 1) {
       // Not an admin user, go back where we came from
       $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
    $this->idEmpty($id, 'index');

        if (!empty($this->data)) 
        {
            if ($this->User->save($this->data)) 
            {
        $this->flashSuccess('The User has been saved', 'index');
            } 
            else 
            {
        $this->flashWarning('The User could not be saved. Please, try again.');
            }
        }
        if (empty($this->data)) 
        {
            $this->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
        }

    }


    function delete($id = null) 
    {
 if(!$this->Session->read('Auth.User.admin') == 1) {
       // Not an admin user, go back where we came from
       $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
           $this->idEmpty($id, 'index');

        if ($this->User->del($id)) 
        {
      $this->flashSuccess('User Deleted', 'index');
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that I would recommend the below solution only in a smaller/private application. Larger apps/enterprise apps should really run on ACL.

That being said, what you could do is use admin routing and a minor database adjustment.

1. Enable the admin Routing prefix by uncommenting the `Routing.prefix` line in `app/config/core.php`
2. Adjust your users table to hold an additional `BOOLEAN` type field called `admin` (with default value 0).
3. Set the `admin` field value to 1 for your admin user.

Then create your edit/delete functions like this:

```
function admin_edit($id = null) {
    if(!$this->Session->read('Auth.User.admin') == 1) {
       // Not an admin user, go back where we came from
       $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }

    // Rest of your logic goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help Oldskool. I have updated the post with the revised edit and delete actions/methods on my users_controller. The final thing I need to achieve is a check so that only the admin user has a tab displayed on the navigation that says 'users'. This tab will route them to the index action of the users_controller.php where  they will manager users and the secured edit and delete actions will be available to them. Will this check be implemented on home.ctp? header.ctp? Or possibly both?

Comment: I'm not sure whether the syntax is correct for the updated edit and delete functions that I have posted above. It has not caused the application to crash or thrown an error.

Comment: @BenAidley Yes, you can add the same check to your views in order to make it appear in your navigation menu. Like: `if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.admin') == 1) { echo $this->Html->link('Users', array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index')); }`